# Reload php file retrieved with 'require' on every function call

Tags: php, require, opcache

Inside a server-side PHP script, called via an `AJAX Request #1`, I'm requiring a PHP `script A`, by using the `require` statement.

On the page on from which that `AJAX Request #1` can be fired, I also provide a way to modify that `script A` programmatically, with a button hit on that same page, via another `AJAX Request #2`.

Consequently, for everything to work properly without having to reload the page, I need to make sure, on each time the `AJAX Request #1` gets fired, that the newest state of `script A` will be required for the execution of the response to `AJAX Request #1`. This sometimes worked, but other times not, and I couldn't really figure out why, because my server always replied with a 200 status code, but sometimes with a non-updated response (showing me that the "old" `script A` has been required on the server-side to create the response to `AJAX Request #1`).

After digging somewhat deeper, I found out about OPcache (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php). When checking with `phpinfo()`, I confirmed that it's up an running on my server, so I guess that must be the reason. My required `script A` may be cached, and thus it's not always the updated `script A` which is used on every `AJAX Request #1`.

My ideal goal would be to reload the newest `script A` via the `require script A` statement of the PHP script which replies to `AJAX Request #1`, with every single request.

I then came across the following functions, where we come to my questions:

- `opcache_is_script_cached()`
- `opcache_invalidate()`
- `opcache_reset()`

My questions are:

1) If I use `opcache_is_script_cached()` to check if the corresponding `script A` file is in my opcache, I weirdly get `1` as response, and not `TRUE`, as it says in the reference, so I'm first of all unsure about interpreting this `1` as boolean `1`, meaning that the corresponding `script A` is indeed in the opcache? If not, what else does that `1` response mean, and why the default response `TRUE` or `FALSE` is not showing up?

2) I first thought of using `opcache_invalidate()` to remove the `script A` from the cache, before the `require script A` statement, but then read on a contributor's note that this is actually not enough to guarantee the script's removal from the opcache (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.opcache-invalidate.php)?? Consequently, the only solution I see is changing the code in my server-side PHP script, answering to `AJAX Request #1`, from:

`require script A;`

to:

`opcache_reset();`

`require script A;`

As I'm not experienced with opcache, I'm afraid of immediately testing that. Also I do not know what it involves: the script of this question runs on a page of my backend, so it would for example not be the best to clear the whole opcache, and through this also re-increase front-end script require loads etc., with each time the `AJAX Request #1`would be fired. In other words, is `opcache_reset()` the only solution I have to reach what I want, and what exactly does it involve / remove from the opcache?

Comment: If you need to modify or create php files on the fly, the design of your application is bad.

Comment: I purposely chose to not do this little part with a database, but with a second php file, simply containing an array serving as "very small database". As the requests / modification to this database will be very frequently made, I wanted to avoid that any of these data maniuplations use database connections etc. The array contains the value and name of option tags which should be added to a select menu on the page, dynamically, so I supposed that building up these select menus by iterating through the required array is much faster and less resource intense than if I would use a database. No?

Comment: Also, many other scripts also use the data of this array by simply accessing it and iterating through the array. If I think of making database queries in all of these scripts, I'm afraid of increasing my server loads unnecessarily high. Maybe the use of a database for ```AJAX Request #1``` only, and the use of the php ```script A``` requiring for all the other scripts may be the best compromise then (while they both have the same contents)?

Comment: What do you actually worry about? Database is easier to maintain, consistent and by far more efficient in handling data than your file-based approach can ever be. In any scenario, a database will be the preferable choice, that's why all smart developers use it for their applications... Don't do micro-optimizations in development!

Comment: Thx for ur insistance man, I was just afraid of using too many resources with constant database retrievals, but it's still much faster, didn't expect that.. Cheers man!